# meaning of -a -z in if [ -z "$ENV_VAR" -a -z "$ENV_VAR2"] bash conditional

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

What is is meaning of `-a -z` in

```
if [ -z "$ENV_VAR" -a -z "$ENV_VAR2"]; then
...
fi
```

bash conditional?

The first -z checks if **$ENV_VAR** defined according to

> -z string True if the length of string is zero.

What does `-a -z` combination test with relation to **ENV_VAR2**?

according to the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)

> -a file True if file exists.

however, **ENV_VAR2** may contain text only, not a file name.

Comment: I suspect the author is using -a to perform a boolean "AND".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[ -z "$ENV_VAR" -a -z "$ENV_VAR2" ]` has 2 conditions **ANDed** together using `-a` switch:

What it means is this:

- `-z "$ENV_VAR"`: `$ENV_VAR` is empty
- `-a`: and
- `-z "$ENV_VAR2"`: `$ENV_VAR2` is empty

btw if you're using `bash` you can refactor this condition to make it bit more succinct:

```
[[ -z $ENV_VAR && -z $ENV_VAR2 ]]
```

Comment: If you're not using `[[ ]]`, you should use `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` instead, see [Bash Pitfall #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf6).

Answer (score 1):

Please try this "man test".

Ideally, in that output, you'll see that -a performs an "AND" between two expressions.

Comment: That gets you the man page for the external `test`/`[` command, but in Bash, they're built-ins, the help for which is in `help test` (or `man bash`).

Answer (score 1):

It's "and".

See `man test`

```
EXPRESSION1 -a EXPRESSION2
  both EXPRESSION1 and EXPRESSION2 are true
```

Examples:

```
$ [ -z "" -a -z "" ] && echo Hello
Hello

$ [[ -z "" -a -z "" ]] && echo Hello
bash: syntax error in conditional expression
bash: syntax error near `-a'
```

If used with single `[` it is the "and" from `test`. If used with `[[` it is the file check from bash.

The bash solution:

```
$ [[ -z "" && -z "" ]] && echo Hello
Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

For POSIX compatibility, `[[ ... && ... ]]` is not available, but `-a` is considered obsolete (and optional) by POSIX, so use two separate `[` commands instead.

```
if [ -z "$ENV_VAR" ] && [ -z "$ENV_VAR2" ]; then
...
fi
```